# Problems with notifyAll() with different java versions

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I have made a code for multithread exercise, and found something wrong on it.

```
public class MultiThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t=new MyMultiThread("Thread1");
        Thread t1=new MyMultiThread("Thread2");
        Thread t2=new MyMultiThread("Thread3");
        t.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
class MyMultiThread extends  Thread {
    private static int num = 1;
    public int count;
    public int work;//get thread id
    private static int sequence;

    public MyMultiThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this.getClass()) {
            work = Integer.parseInt(this.getName().substring(2));//get the final number of thread's name
            while (num <= 21) {
                while (work != sequence%3+1 ) {
                    this.getClass().notifyAll();
                    try {
                        this.getClass().wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                count++;
                System.out.println(getName() + ":" + num++);
                if (count == 3) {
                    count = 0;
                    sequence++;
                    this.getClass().notifyAll();
                    try {
                        this.getClass().wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            this.getClass().notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

First my java version is 13,and found my code doesn't run properly. It seems that my code didn't have any logical problems on it, but there's always has one thread that might not be notified, which makes my code in a error sequence. So I changed my java version from 13 to 14, 11LTS, and finally solved the problem with java 8. But why? I didn't see any update in wait() or notify() method, that made me confused for days.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(this.getName().substring(2));` does this really work? I mean, `substring(2)` gets the substring starting from index 2. Which means that the thread names you give, like for example *Thread2*, will become *read2* and *read2* is not an integer at radix 10. I ran your code and just threw immediately `NumberFormatException`s in each `Thread`. Maybe a typo?

Comment: I understand though that the point is `substring(6)` and not `substring(2)`. Anyway, what does it print in the case of Java 11, 13, and 14? Can you provide some output for cases it works (ie the expected output) and for cases it doesn't?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the value of the substring(), because I used to type the name in another language. In English, it should be substring(6).

Comment: On jdk8(which the code was run properly),is like this`Thread1:1
Thread1:2
Thread1:3
Thread2:4
Thread2:5
Thread2:6
Thread3:7
Thread3:8
Thread3:9
Thread1:10
Thread1:11
Thread1:12
Thread2:13
Thread2:14
Thread2:15
Thread3:16
Thread3:17
Thread3:18
Thread1:19
Thread1:20
Thread1:21`

Comment: On java 11 or higher, it can only print correctly form Thread 1 to 3 for the first round, then Thread 1 disappear, Thread 2 and 3 paint in an endless loop.